# Guidance on API testing in Drupal 8

Tags: api, testing, drupal, codeception

I am working on a Drupal 8 project which uses the inbuilt API which is very good. But I wish to add some Codeception to test the API endpoints but can't find any documentation.

Has anyone implemented API tests for this before that can show me how to get started?

Comment: Look at REST module. Since there is no Drupal module for Codeception, you will have to use PhpBrowser for communication and test your site over HTTP.

Comment: I recommend to use Guzzle.